# list and the array not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am trying to make a to-do list and while applying the delete feature, the data is being removed in the function but not from the items array also, the list is not being re-rendered even if the useState is used.

```
interface Props {
  items: string[];
}

const TaskList = ({ items }: Props) => {
  const [taskListItem, taskListItemAdd] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const deleteItem = (item: string, num: number) => {
    console.log(item + " is deleted.");
    // delete items[num];
    items = [...items.slice(0, num), ...items.slice(num + 1)];
    // console.log("joined: ", items);
    taskListItemAdd([...taskListItem ,...items]);
    console.log(taskListItem);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {items.map((item, num) => {
          // console.log(num, item);
          return (
            <li className="list-group-item " key={num}>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => deleteItem(item, num)}
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  className="bi bi-check"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z" />
                </svg>
              </button>
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default TaskList;
```

This is the code where items is a array props taken in from another component. When the **deleteItem** is called, then the items array is edited which I checked from `console.log` but the **items** array still has the initial array data and resets everytime.

For example, I gave the input ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] in the items array and if I clicked delete near for **b** then the **items array** in the **deleteItem function** shows *["a", "c", "d", "e"]* but the ***items mapped*** shows **["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]** which means the *items is not being saved or re-rendered*. What approach should I take to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` isn't part of this component's state.  It's provided as a prop from the parent component.

This is an attempt to mutate that prop:

```
items = [...items.slice(0, num), ...items.slice(num + 1)];
```

Which won't work.  Props and state are immutable.  If you want to modify what's being provided by the parent component, then the parent component (which holds the actual state here) needs to provide a way to modify it.

For example, presumably you currently have something like this using the component shown:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();

// some component logic to populate items, etc.

// then, somewhere in the rendering...
return (
  <TaskList items={items} />
);
```

What `TaskList` is missing in this case is `setItems`:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();

// some component logic to populate items, etc.

// then, somewhere in the rendering...
return (
  <TaskList items={items} setItems={setItems} />
);
```

Which it could then use to update `items`:

```
const TaskList = ({ items, setItems }: Props) => {

  //...

  const deleteItem = (item: string, num: number) => {
    setItems([...items.slice(0, num), ...items.slice(num + 1)]);
    console.log(item + " is deleted.");
    taskListItemAdd([...taskListItem ,...items]);
  };

  //...
}
```

---

*As an aside... It's not at all clear to me what `taskListItem` is meant to be doing here, so I just didn't modify that part.  But I'd recommend being very careful about locally duplicating state that's provided from a parent component.  It can get confusing and buggy pretty quickly.  Since nothing in this component actually **uses** this state value, I'd recommend removing it entirely and re-thinking whatever it's meant to accomplish.*

Comment: The `taskListItem` was an idea to create a useState so that, I could make the UI render after the items is changed. But thankyou, I did not know that props were not mutable, this helped me a lot and the problem is solved.